# How to scroll two or more JTables with a single Scrollbar?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

How can I use one scroll from one `JScrollPane` to move another or more than one `JScrollPane`?

In example:

I have three `JTable`s in separate `JScrollPane`s. I want to *bind* the scrollpanes to each other.

If I'll use one - the another will scroll the same way.

Some kind of `Listener`s which i can't find?

Any sugestions?

Best regards.

Comment: Why not make one table out of the sets of data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An approach that preserves the `JTables`' headers would be to use the same `BoundedRangeModel` for each `JScrollPane`'s vertical scrollbar and add each ScrollPane to a single `JPanel`.

```
class ParallelTables {
    static JScrollPane createTable() {
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(100, 2);
        for (int row=model.getRowCount(); --row>=0;) {
            model.setValueAt(row, row, 0);
        }
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        return new JScrollPane(table);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        JScrollPane scrollerA = createTable();
        JScrollPane scrollerB = createTable();
        scrollerA.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        // the following statement binds the same BoundedRangeModel to both vertical scrollbars.
        scrollerA.getVerticalScrollBar().setModel(
                scrollerB.getVerticalScrollBar().getModel());
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(scrollerA);
        panel.add(scrollerB);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Reference:**

- https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1348214

Comment: @mKorbel no need to go indirect if you can share a model :-)

Answer (score 2):

> I have three JTables in separate JScrollPanes. I want to "bound" scroll to each other.

Don't put the JTables in JScrollPanes.  Put each JTable into a JPanel, and put the 3 JPanels into one JScrollPane.

It would probably be easier to combine your 3 JTables into one JTable.

Comment: 2nd para. is worthy of a +1, but the first para. will cause the table headers to not appear.

Answer (score 1):

David Kroukamp's suggestion was to have the scrollbars share a model, like this:

```
    scrollerA.getVerticalScrollBar().setModel(
            scrollerB.getVerticalScrollBar().getModel());
```

That certainly works fine, but if you want to use a single scrollbar for all tables, it's even simpler to replace one scrollbar with the other:

```
    scrollerA.setVerticalScrollBar(
            scrollerB.getVerticalScrollBar());
```

Only one scrollbar appears with this method, and it scrolls both tables.