# two synchronized scrollBars don't work

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I need to do two element with one horizontal scroll bar. I did:

```
JTable myTable = new JTable(10, 5);
JTable myTable2 = new JTable(1, 5);
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
JScrollPane SP1 = new JScrollPane(myTable, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        SP1.setColumnHeaderView(myTable.getTableHeader());

        JScrollPane SP2 = new JScrollPane(myTable2, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        SP2.getHorizontalScrollBar().setModel(SP1.getHorizontalScrollBar().getModel());    
        panel.add(SP1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(SP2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        getContentPane.add(panel);
```

I need to scroll my SP2 together with the SP1.
But They don't. I can't see horizontal scrollBar after SP2 panel.
And no one element hasn't horizontal scrolling.
Please, help me to find what I missed.

I looked the example in that post [How to scroll two or more JTables with a single Scrollbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060587/how-to-scroll-two-or-more-jtables-with-a-single-scrollbar)

Comment: Your code example is incomplete. What is `GrillaLineas`, `myTable`, `myPanel`, `x`, `y`, `w`, `h`? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Frist of all get rid of all the setBounds() statements. That code does nothing. The layout manager will set the size and location of the components.

Comment: @camickr I did. Thanks

Comment: I solve, but scroll bar is between two tables, not after both.  
     
panel.setLayout(null);
JScrollPane SP1 = new JScrollPane(myTable);
        SP1.setColumnHeaderView(myTable.getTableHeader());  SP1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
...        
JScrollPane SP2 = new JScrollPane(myTable2);
        SP2.getHorizontalScrollBar().setModel(SP1.getHorizontalScrollBar().getModel());    

        panel.add(SP);
        panel.add(SP2);